# How to install experimental packages?

Tags: wine, packages, debian-squeeze, dependencies, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I am running Debian Squeeze and would like to install the Wine experimental package of Sid.

My Questions:

1. Where do I find the package?
2. Is there a way to include the package into the software sources and install it with Synaptic?
3. How are dependencies dealt with if an experimental package requires updates of dependencies that are also experimental? Could it be that other programs will become unstable due to the dependency "update"?

Answer (score 0):

## Example - stable

The sources.list for using stable reads --

```
  deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
  deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
  deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free
```

## Example - testing

You need to include the stable lines, and then add three lines with a s/stable/testing/g, giving the file:

```
  deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
  deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US stable/non-US main contrib non-free
  deb http://security.debian.org stable/updates main contrib non-free

  deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
  deb http://non-us.debian.org/debian-non-US testing/non-US main contrib non-free
  deb http://security.debian.org testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

Source: http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/COMPUTING/debian-principles.html

On the testing, notice that the sources are accessing stable and testing.

You can find your sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`